# -fno-stack-protector is not working

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I have written the following C program to see the working of buffer overflows. I have saved this program file with name **bo.c**

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int authentication(char *key)
    {
        int auth=0;
        char pass[10];
        strcpy(pass, key);
        if(strcmp(pass, "hello")==0)
            auth=1; 
        else
            auth=0;
        return auth;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        if(authentication(argv[1]))
        {
            printf("----------------------------------\nACCESS  GRANTED\n---------------------------------");
}
        else
        {
            printf("Access Denied! Wrong password!");
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

But I am not able to see the effect of buffer overflow because the stack is protected. But when I am compiling it with the -fno-stack-protector flag, it is showing that it is an unrecognized option.

[image]

What is the problem here? Am I doing something wrong in the usage of the **gcc** command?

Comment: Options available are depending on your gcc version and how it was compiled.

Comment: I can't see that option in the documentation for 8.1 at least - look up your version's manual [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). The 8.1 doc for -fstack-protector is under [Program Instrumentation Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly doing the command but it is unrecgonized due to your configuration.

`gcc -fno-stack-protector bo.c`

I would recommend reinstalling gcc or trying in another linux distro. Also feel free to look at this article on [the use of -fno-stack-protector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712972/what-is-the-use-of-fno-stack-protector) as it gives some insight as to why it may be disabled. (Do to possible configurations with Makefile disabling the flag)

--------Edit----------

After looking further into this, I would recommend looking at: `-fstack-protector-all` or `-fstack-protector`

I was messing around with your code and found this might be what you're trying to do and your current setup may allow it.

[My CMD Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIEOV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct command like this :

```
gcc -o bo bo.c -fno-stack-protector
```